# Replace a character in all post titles and slugs

Tags: mysql, bulk

I have hundreds of posts whose titles are of the form `XmY`, where `X` and `Y` are natural numbers, for example `18m324`.

I'd like to replace `m` with `p` in all post titles and slugs, while keeping `X` and `Y` unchanged. How to do it in phpmyadmin?

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_title = 
REPLACE(post_title, 'm' , 'p')
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish';
```

This code should replace in the titles, but what about the slugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slugs are saved in the very same table but in the `post_name` column. So your query would look like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_name = 
REPLACE(post_name, 'm' , 'p')
WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish';
```

By the way, I'd suggest you to use `$wpdb->posts` instead of just `wp_posts` ( then it would be compatible with different prefixes, but it's not important if it's just a "local" script )

Comment: thanks! you mean `UPDATE $wpdb->posts` instead of `UPDATE wp_posts` ?

Comment: @soundwave yes :)